# How to setup common php session across multiple servers using redis

Tags: amazon-ec2, php5, redis

We have one main domain and 4 sub domains running different  instances and using same remote mysql database server. Some domains using PHP 5.6 and some using 5.5. we want to have our domains sharing the same PHP session, So that we can keep user data across these domains. I saw two methods  Storing Sessions in a Database and using memcached. We are using redis on each servers.

Is it possible to set-up a centralised **redis server to handle common php session across multiple servers**

Answer (score 0):

In order to use Redis to handle PHP sessions across multiple servers, you need to install the phpredis PHP extension and configure Redis as PHP session handler in php.ini on each server.

Comment: The question is a bit more complex than that. OP wants to share not just across multiple servers, but across multiple *domains*.

Comment: @ceejayoz Yes, share across subdomains